# CasperJS sendAjax return null

Tags: javascript, casperjs

of the code on CasperJS

```javascript
var data = this.evaluate(function(url) {
     return JSON.parse(__utils__.sendAJAX(url, 'GET', null, false));
}, {url: url});

this.then(function() {
     require('utils').dump(data);
});
```

by url

```php
<?php
echo 'zzz';
exit;
```

To the url request comes in, I checked.
However, data shows

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "null" }
```

Somebody tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Please describe *in detail* what the problem is. Where does that `array(1)...` output come from? Your php code doesn't return valid JSON. So obviously the `JSON.parse()` will throw an error and `null` will be returned from `evaluate()`.

Comment: @Artjom B. I run a script in the browser

Comment: @Artjom B. I return and json, but get everything is null

Answer (score 1):

Add option --web-security=no

exec('/usr/local/bin/casperjs --web-security=no